# Android, AsyncTask, long running processes, and orientation changes

Tags: android

In the past, orientation changes and AsyncTask (and other long running background tasks) have not played well with each other.  There's always been the issue of knowing what tasks (or threads) are still running in the newly created activity (from an orientation change), and what to do when a task ends while an Activity isn't attached.

Even with Fragments and the LoaderManager, this still seems to be a problem to me.

What is the preferred way these days, to manage arbitrary long running tasks and orientation changes?  To know what tasks are running in the newly created activity.  To make sure a task doesn't try to deliver it's information when an Activity isn't attached.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you rewrite your question, replacing the word "process" in places where you do not really mean "process" but instead mean something else. An OS process has a very specific definition, one which causes your question to make little sense (e.g,. processes don't deliver information, activities don't create processes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my program I just put

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

in my activities in the manifest and be done with it. After 1 year I have had 0 problems.

Comment: How do you go about handling the config changes yourself?

Comment: I have found that having that in the manifest causes the activity to not be recreated, thus solving all your problems. I was going to look into handling it myself, but found it unnecessary in practice. It works how you would expect/want it to.

Comment: Wow.  I always strayed away from this because it seemed more complicated than I wanted.  You're right, it seems to work how I want it to.

Comment: I have some pretty complicated things, that would be terrible if anything went wrong, and so far so good :D

Comment: Many thanks sir, this is way easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Note that for API level 13 or higher you should also specify `screenSize`.

Answer (score 0):

As other post suggests, you can use android:configChanges=xxx.

BUT, this is not always desired. Android is designed to kill activity on configuration change, and create new one, and you may benefit from this in some situation, by providing alternative screen layout. 
This makes sense for example in multi-pane app, where landscape orientation shows different views than portrait orientation.

So to return to your question: I didn't read about preferred way to handle long running operations, but from own experiences I'd suggest to store such task in persistent activity state (saved/restored in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance/onCreate), or using persistent Fragments.

If your Activity detects that some task is already running, it can give it chance to recreate dialog to show its progress.

And note: orienation change is not the only that can make your activity to be recreated. Be prepared for language change, docking, and other possibilities :) But still, orientation change is the most common one.

Comment: Persistent Fragments still has the possibility of trying to deliver results when the Activity is not attached.  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance cannot store, say, an active network connection.  The problem here is not storing state for the configuration change, it's making sure the data isn't delivered when an Activity isn't attached, or making sure it doesn't try to deliver it to a dead Activity

Answer (score -1):

Its the same as it always has been: use a service. Broadcast events from your service and catch them in your activity (or some intermediate layer). Your activity can then choose what to do with those events based on its state.

This is a rather broad question.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem that Services are meant to solve.  It seems that if your application doesn't have tasks are independent of your Activity lifecycle, a Service would just be a waste of resources.